# Forcing all paragraphs to expand and match the height of the highest one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to "expand" all paragraphs to match the height of the highest paragraph. Note that the font size is responsive.

Example:

[image]

As you can see in the right image I want to change that paragraph's height to match the first one height.

Can this be done?

Comment: @matthias thanks, and I tried with jquery and succeeded, but next problem appeared: now images got shrunk, because changing size of that header (images have img-fluid set to them

Comment: Maybe add a follow up question for this as now it's a different problem.